# Outbound address of Azure function not within published outbound addresses

Tags: c#, azure-functions

In the following code, I use `_client` in my timer-triggered Azure Function on Linux to send a Http GET request to `DEMO_URL`. I suppose the `X-Forwarded-For` of this request should be some address in [outbound addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=portal#find-outbound-ip-addresses) (`104.xxx.xxx.xxx`), but it is `20.210.135.122`.

Is there any way to restrict `_client` to use outbound addresses so that I can easily setup a firewall of `DEMO_URL`'s server?

```cs
public class MyFunctionApp
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    public MyFunctionApp(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    }

    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%SCHEDULE%")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            string url = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DEMO_URL");
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless there is some kind of special HttpClientHandler for use in Azure Functions that lets you control this, then it will probably be some configuration option on Azure itself. I don't know about Azure, but on GCP you'd have to pass traffic through an outbound NAT.

Comment: It seems like the same thing on Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-nat-gateway

Comment: As @DiplomacyNotWar says - this is more related to Azure infrastructure as opposed to the `HTTPClient`; the client is merely a client. An IP address is specified at the network level.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Thanks for replying. I searched this document before, but I just wonder is there any way simpler to do this.